# Gumbel-Softmax like function

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to train my DNN models and face some mathematical problems.

Let me explain my goal. Consider an input tensor like [1,2,3,4,5]. I aim to obtain a one-hot encoded vector of the argmax of this input tensor, which would result in [0,0,0,0,1].

The issue is that this process needs to be differentiable.
In my research, I’ve looked into the Gumbel-Softmax and softargmax functions.
From my understanding, Gumbel-Softmax does not guarantee an output of [0,0,0,0,1] as it follows the categorical distribution of the input tensor.

With the softargmax function, I obtained an approximate argmax index. However, after applying one-hot encoding, I ended up with NaN loss values.
Is one-hot encoding not differentiable, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

To summarize:

1.Are there any alternatives to Gumbel-Softmax for achieving a differentiable one-hot(argmax(input_tensor))?

2.Is one-hot encoding non-differentiable?

Answer (score 2):

One-hot encoding is indeed an inherently non-differentiable operation because it involves an argmax operation that produces discrete outputs, making it piecewie-constant. However, you may always relax argmax with [softargmax](https://medium.com/@nicolas.ugrinovic.k/soft-argmax-soft-argmin-and-other-soft-stuff-7f94e6120dff).

You may want to explore the Straight Through Gumbel-Softmax to address your first issue too. See also Proposition 1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.04838.pdf) (which is nothing more than an application of Jensen's inequality).